# Reference forwarding in Visual Studio 2010 (from library to executable)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, system.data.sqlite, project-reference

I have a C# library which has System.Data.SQLite as a reference, and an executable (as a 2nd project) which uses the library.

In the library, I have a function which references a class in System.Data.SQLite (Specifically the `SQLiteDataReader` class):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SQLiteFetch<T>(Func<SQLiteDataReader, T> formator, string connectionString, string query)
```

The library compiles properly, but not the executable which calls this function.

This comes up as an error on build, saying I "must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'". I get that it's due to the IEnumerable, but why isn't the reference forwarded through my library? Do I really have to add a reference to System.Data.SQLite in my executable as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to add a reference to your executable because  when you are creating your `formator`, .NET expects it to be of type `Func<SQLiteDataReader, T>`. And since your executable doesn't have a reference to System.Data.SQLite, it doesn't know how to deal with your formator. This is the case even if you pass `null` as the formator.

Answer (score 2):

An assembly is only aware of its immediate references (such as your library), and does not recursively load the references of its references, so you will have to add the reference to your executable.

Your library can include a wrapper class that inherits from SQLiteDataReader to get around this, but I don't see any particular advantage of doing this other than if you really don't want the executable to have the extra reference.

Comment: I'll give +1 since you are correct, but there are advantages to wrapping 3rd party libraries.  If you are providing a library to be used by an application (especially external-facing), you don't want your users to care about the implementation details of your library.  In this case, it is better to abstract the referenced library away and control their access to your system through a wrapper.  I agree, this isn't always necessary, but there are definitive times when you want to do this.